# Android sharing View Flipper content with other apps (twitter, gmail etc..)

Tags: android, sharing, viewflipper

I am trying to share a flip view content with other apps such as twitter, gmail etc. However the share button works but does not show the flashcard content instead it shows a text that says "android.widget.ViewFlipper@40523fc0".  Any help please I have been struggling with for a while. Below is my Java code. The xml code contains only couple buttons and a text view.

public class Jokes extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener {

```
ViewFlipper flippy;
Random r = new Random();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jokes);
    flippy = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    flippy.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bShare);
    b.setOnTouchListener(this);
    String s [ ]= {"abc", "DEF", "ghi"};

}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int i = r.nextInt();
    flippy.setDisplayedChild(r.nextInt(4));
    flippy.showNext();



}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  ""+ flippy);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Udir/Share"));
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to store the data you want to share as the tag of buttons.

```
b.setTag("abc"); // Whatever you want to share
```

This way you can get the data from the button in the event callback.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bShare: {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      intent.setType("text/plain");
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (String) v.getTag());
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Udir/Share"));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have many texts that I would like to display in a Flip View and put  next button for the next text, previous button for the previous text and share button that enables the user to share the content from the flip view. Having a setTag will only enable me to share what I as a developer want not the user.

Comment: Just like you set the content to the views inside of the FlipView, set the content as the tag of the share button.